# Need help understanding this text extracted from B.Stroustrup's new book

Tags: c++, multithreading, memory, c++11

In section `41.2.1 Memory Location` of his new book, B.Stroustrup writes the following:

> Consider two global variables **b** and **c**:
>
> ```
> // thread1
> char c = 0;
> void f()
> {
>    c = 1;
>    int x = c;
> } 
>
> // thread2
> char b = 0;
> void g()
> {
>    b = 1;
>    int y = b;
> }
> ```
>
> Now, x==1 and y==1, as anyone would expect. Why is this even worth saying? Consider what might happen if a linker allocated
>   **c** and **b** in the same word in memory and (like most modern hardware) the machine could not load or store anything smaller than a
>   word:
>
> [image]
>
> Without a well-defined and reasonable memory model, thread 1 might
>   read the word containing **b** and **c**, change **c**, and write the
>   word back into memory. At the same time thread 2 could do the same
>   with **b**. Then, whichever thread managed to read the word first  and
>   wichever thread managed to write its result back into memory last
>   would determine the result. We might get **10**, **01**, or **11**
>   (but not **00**). The memory model saves us from such chaos; we get
>   **11**. The reason that **00** cannot happen is that the initialization of **b** and **c** are done (by the compiler or the linker) before
>   either thread starts.

Assuming that the phrase:

> We might get **10**, **01**, or **11** (but not **00**)

refers to the final values of the variables **x** and **y** respectively, how could we get **10** and **01** without a sensible memory model. I just can't see how this would be possible.

I also couldn't understand what the author meant to say when he wrote the last sentence above:

> The reason that **00** cannot happen is that the initialization of
>   **b** and **c** are done (by the compiler or the linker) before either thread starts.

Comment: Thread1 reads `00`. Thread2 reads `00`. Thread1 writes `10`. Thread2 writes `01`. Thread1 re-reads `01`, and saves 0 in `x`. Thread2 re-reads `01`, and saves 1 in `y`.

Comment: The thread is not just writing b, it's writing a word in memory.  When the thread starts, it pulls the whole word in BEFORE c has been set. See above comment for a timeline.

Comment: As for the final sentence: "The reason that 00 cannot happen is that the initialization of b and c are done (by the compiler or the linker) before either thread starts."

Try "the process of writing 00 (initializing b and c) is already complete before either thread starts, so there's no risk of that write of 00 to the work happening in the middle of the thread execution".

Comment: By the way, exactly this may happen to bit fields under C++11 memory model. Adjacent bit fields belong to the same memory locations; concurrent access to such fields constitutes a data race, and exhibits undefined behavior.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik What do you mean by Thread1 reads 00?

Comment: Thread1 reads in a word of memory that happens to contain values of both `c` and `b`. The portion of that word that represents the value of `c` holds 0; so does the portion of that word that represents the value of `b`.

Comment: Which book is this exactly, just to be complete?

Comment: @user1767754 The C++ Programming Language 4th edition, from Bjarne Stroustrup.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason that you could get 01 or 10 without a sensible memory model is because thread operations occur concurrently and the read and write of the memory are not atomic. They require two steps - step 1: read, step 2: write. Without a sensible memory model, the following would be possible:

Thread 1: Reads  00     Memory:00

Thread 2: Reads  00     Memory:00

Thread 1: Writes 10     Memory:10

Thread 2: Writes 01     Memory:01

Result: 01

The problem of multiple threads accessing the same resource is common with multi-threaded programming. For example, multiple threads that need access to the same static member variable. The way that we protect against threads trampling over each other is with mutexes and critical sections. However, in the case that is presented we don't need to do that because the memory model handles it for us (is sensible).

The reason that 00 is not possible: the memory is initialised to 00 before either thread starts, so neither thread tramples over what the other thread has done and sets the memory to 00.

Comment: I finally got the idea. Tks (+1)